# Get the Contents of a QComboBox

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring, qcombobox

I need to get an `QStringList` or an array containing all `QString`s in a `QComboBox`.

I can't find a `QComboBox` method that does this, in fact I can't even find a `QAbstractItemModel` method that does this.

Is this *really* my only option:

```
std::vector< QString > list( myQComboBox.count() );

for( auto i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
{
    list[i] = myQComboBox.itemText( i );
}
```

Comment: There is no such function, AFAK. Why don't you like the approach you use (iteration over all items in the combo box)?

Comment: @vahancho I presume it to be quite wasteful, especially as the size of the `QComboBox` grows.

Comment: But maybe storing the content of the combo box into another container is also wasteful? Why do you need that? This can explain, why there is no such function in the API.

Comment: What does the container of values get you that the member function `QComboBox::itemText` cannot?

Comment: I am going to clear `myQComboBox` and repopulate it, I need to identify elements that have changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QAbstractItemModel` can contain images, trees other kinds of data that can be kept in `QVariant`. That is why you can't get a `QStringList` from it. It is pointless.

However, there is a class `QStringListModel` inherited from `QAbstractItemModel` that is intended to keep strings. And as you can expect it has method `stringList()`.

`QComboBox` allows you to change a default model which it uses to another one. By default it uses `QStandardItemModel`. Change it to a string list model after creating the combo box.

```
 QStringListModel* cbModel = new QStringListModel();
 comboBox->setModel(cbModel);
```

Now you can get what you want:

```
QStringList list = cbModel->stringList();
```

Comment: This is not the solution I'd hoped for but it does legitimately solve the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Your answer looks fine, but you could also use a QStringList instead of a vector.

```
QStringList itemsInComboBox; 
for (int index = 0; index < ui->combo_box->count(); index++)
    itemsInComboBox << ui->combo_box->itemText(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do a premature optimization. Your code is ok. You may use `qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(combo.model());` to get extended access to combobox data.

Also, you can implement your own QAbstractItemModel which will store data as QStringList, and provide access to it.